# If ball hits the arm protector that is touching the glove holding bat, is it out?

Tags: rules, cricket

If the ball hits the arm protector that is touching the glove of the leading arm in question that is holding the bat, is the catch considered legal, and the batsman out?

Answer (score 3):

If the ball hits the glove of the batsman and the catch is legal, the batsman is judged OUT. Otherwise, if the ball hits the arm-guard and the catch is taken, the batsman is judged NOT OUT.

[Caught OUT rules in Cricket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caught)

Comment: Apparently the rules have been changed in test cricket, and now it is considered NOT OUT

Answer (score 2):

**`NOT OUT` even if arm protector that is touching the glove of the leading arm.**

The rule is that `OUT` only if ball directly touches glove.

It's something like that what if ball touches helmet and bat is in touch of helmet simple thing is that ball should touch bat or glove Hope you understand better...!!